# Handling optional commas in text

Tags: memoir, characters

I'm writing a document in Danish using the `memoir` LaTeX class.

In Danish we have two different systems for placing commas in a text; one system uses many commas, the other system uses fewer commas. I want my document to be able to generate both.

The simple solution is to introduce an `\optionalcomma` command, and then define it as either

```
\newcommand{\optionalcomma}{, }
```

or

```
\newcommand{\optionalcomma}{ }
```

depending on what output I want.

However, placing innumerable `\optionalcomma` commands in the text, makes it harder for me, the author, to read.

So I wondered, is it possible to have a very unobtrusive way of writing the optional comma. Is there, for example, a way to use a double comma (or some other "small footprint" command) for an optional comma?

This would enable me to write this in my LaTeX file:

```
Han så,, at jeg kom, og at jeg var glad.
```

and with minimal changes to the LaTeX file have it produce either this output:

```
Han så, at jeg kom, og at jeg var glad.
```

or this:

```
Han så at jeg kom, og at jeg var glad.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unobtrusive parts in a TeX file can be made with a single character if it is an *active character*. Here is how you can do it with `;` for `\optionalcomma` (if you don't need real semicolons).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\optionalcomma}{,}
% \newcommand{\optionalcomma}{}

\catcode`;=\active
\newcommand;{\optionalcomma}

\begin{document}
Well, what do you think; about this?

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: You will want to move the ``\catcode`;=\active`` section after `\begin{document}`.  This might or might not also break TikZ.

Answer (score 11):

Piece of cake if you're free to use LuaLaTeX. :-)

The code below sets up two Lua functions, called `functionA` and `functionB`, and two LaTeX utility macros, called `\OptionA` and `\OptionB` to activate the respective Lua functions. By "activating" a Lua function, I mean assigning it to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates on the input at a very early stage, i.e., *before* TeX starts its usual macro expansion operations. Both `functionA` and `functionB` employ Lua's powerful `gsub` ("global substitution") string function.

I would assume that, in practice, your document will only contain either an `\OptionA` directive or an `\OptionB` directive. Ideally, you'd issue the directive immediately after `\begin{document}`.

The following screenshot shows the output of `Han så,, at jeg kom, og at jeg var glad.` if `\OptionA` is executed at the start of the `document` environment.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

%% Set up two Lua functions:
\directlua{%
function functionA ( s )  return ( s:gsub(",," ,",") )  end
function functionB ( s )  return ( s:gsub(",," , "") )  end
}

%% Set up two LaTeX macros to activate the corresponding Lua functions:
\newcommand{\OptionA}{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer" , functionA , "functionA")}}
\newcommand{\OptionB}{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer" , functionB , "functionB")}}

\begin{document}
\OptionA % or: \OptionB
Han så,, at jeg kom, og at jeg var glad.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

You might (ab)use `\,` for the purpose. Use `\thinspace` if you really need the original meaning of `\,` in text mode.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\optionalcomma\fi}
\newcommand{\optionalcomma}{} % standard, no comma
\newcommand{\activateoptionalcomma}{\renewcommand{\optionalcomma}{,}}
```

### Example with no optional comma

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\optionalcomma\fi}
\newcommand{\optionalcomma}{} % standard, no comma
\newcommand{\activateoptionalcomma}{\renewcommand{\optionalcomma}{,}}

\begin{document}

Well, what do you think\, about this?

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Example with optional comma activated

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\optionalcomma\fi}
\newcommand{\optionalcomma}{} % standard, no comma
\newcommand{\activateoptionalcomma}{\renewcommand{\optionalcomma}{,}}

\activateoptionalcomma

\begin{document}

Well, what do you think\, about this?

\end{document}
```

[image]